# Trying to reinstall macOS (after wiping HD) but can't get past Apple ID and Safari Help Page will NOT open iCloud to let me login!

Tags: macos, icloud, safari, install, apple-id

Basically what the title says. I have a 2009 MacBook Pro and recently wiped the disk to be able to start new. After wiping, I went to redownload Yosemite and of course got the "This item is temporarily unavailable" error after entering my Apple ID.

I did some internet searches and read that a lot of people have gotten past this error by restarting, clicking on Get Help Online, going to icloud.com and logging in with their own Apple ID. After trying again usually they were successful.

I've tried this multiple times in recovery mode and regularly, and every time it says Safari cannot open this page. 100% connected to my own WiFi, yet I don't know how to login and eventually get past this part because I can never open the web page.

Comment: Your Mac support El Capitan. Have you an another Mac to create an install key? I f yes, you can see here : https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT211683

Comment: Hi Kay - Welcome to the community, though sorry to hear you are joining with so serious a problem!

Comment: Kay, when I have started a new Mac afresh, I usually download the new operating system to an thumb drive (to create a bootable drive) _before_ wiping the disk.  Do you have access to a friend's Mac that would allow you to create a bootable drive?  This may put you on a better path than the method you are trying at present.

Comment: There was this problem with high sierra. Some solution [here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/251211674)

Comment: @PtitXav - It's not really a certificate issue any longer, High Sierra & earlier don't know how to use Apple's 2-factor authentication. Basically you have to get anything from the Apple Store from a computer using a newer OS. Mojave is ideal as it's not locked into the 'you can't download this because it won't run on this computer' issue that plagues newer Macs when trying to access earlier OSes.

Comment: @Technocat9 , Regarding accessing a friend's mac, I don't think anyone I'm close to has a mac unfortunately but I will double check! Assuming I find one, where would the OS be saved for me to transfer to the thumb drive, and how do I download it to my mac (since I only have those 4 options when I restart my computer)? If it's a long process, too much to type, I can always google search :) Thank you for the advice! And thank you for the warm welcome, too! :) I'll start looking for access to another mac!

Comment: @Tetsujin are you saying following the steps @ Ptit Xav mentioned in the link, like downloading the certificate to fix the issue, will not work? *Every* single step trying to reinstall OS has had an error that's taken hours if not days to fix! I'm so close, once I log into my icloud on this computer, I'm hoping installation will install perfectly as I'm basically on the last step! If I could just get the page to load! I'm at a loss here, if the certificate will allow the page to load for just this task I have, would you still reccomended trying it? I'm super new here sorry!

Comment: @Ptit Xav Thank you for your response! I read the entire thread and will update if I try it. I appreciate the help!

Comment: @Jean_JD This is awesome info, thank you! Definitely helpful!

Comment: Your Mac is too old to use Internet Recovery, or that would be your 'gat out of jail free' card. You're stuck with a Mac that cannot access the App Store because it cannot use 2FA. You therefore must use a Mac that can. That would ideally be one using Mojave. Newer OSes won't let you download old OSes. Rock/hard place, I'm afraid. Alternatively, take it to a high street Apple Store. They'll do it for free.

Comment: If you still have the original OSX CD delivered with the Mac you can try to restore from it, then upgrade to newer OSX version.

Answer (score 5):

The simplest way forward is to use another Mac to [download OS X El Capitan.](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP728?locale=en_US) Use safari and this link.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT211683

Then from that download, create a bootable USB drive that will install the OS. (This also has links to the download steps)

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201372

You don’t need to sign into iCloud or use an Apple ID to download os installers, so it’s not clear why you’re seeing that error in your symptoms unless the machine has a clock issue where the date and time are so off that the web server encryption fails to negotiate a secure web page.

Answer (score 3):

Since you can boot to OS X Yosemite Recovery, you can install Yosemite without the aid of a DVD, flash drive or another Mac. You will need to download free installation files. One download is the installer for a third party disk partitioning tool called ["GPT fdisk"](https://sourceforge.net/projects/gptfdisk/). The two other downloads are OS X installers from Apple. Basically, you first install Mountain Lion on a new (clean) volume, then use Mountain Lion to install Yosemite on a different new (clean) volume. Finally, the Mountain Lion boot and recovery volumes are converted to free space and the Yosemite volume is expanded to reclaim this free space.

I realize this is a rather lengthly installation procedure. The [answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/431445/trying-to-reinstall-macos-after-wiping-hd-but-cant-get-past-apple-id-and-safa/431945#431945) posted by [bmike](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/5472/bmike) is far simpler and more practice, if your Mac can boot OS X installers from a flash drive and you have another Mac that can install the "Install OS X El Capitan" application from the `InstallMacOSX.dmg` file downloaded from Apple.

Below are the steps to install Yosemite on your Mac.

> Before following the steps posted below, you probably should post the output from the `diskutil list disk0` command so your question. This would allow me to confirm this solution will work with your Mac.

1. Install `gdisk` to your EFI partition. See **Install gdisk from macOS Recovery** in [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/431237/trying-to-rebuild-my-partition-map/431569#431569). This will require the use of Safari. If you get a popup shown below, select the `Cancel` button.

   [image: login popup]
2. Divide partition on the drive where OS X used to reside into two partitions of equal size. Normally, the Disk Utility or `diskutil` command would be used to make the changes. However, since you are booted from the recovery volume on the same drive, neither the Disk Utility or `diskutil` command can be used to successfully make the changes. The procedure given in this step does use the `diskutil` command, *but not to make changes to the this drive*. Other commands are used to make the changes.

   Start by enter the command below to get a list of partitions.

   ```
   diskutil list disk0
   ```

   Below is the output from my test environment. I assume you would get similar output with different sizes.

   ```
   -bash-3.2# diskutil list disk0
   /dev/disk0
      #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
      0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        +268.4 GB   disk0
      1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
      2:                  Apple_HFS Macintosh HD            267.6 GB   disk0s2
      3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s3
   ```

   For this procedure to work, the `Macintosh HD` volume (`disk0s2`) needs to be replaced by two volumes of equal size. Eventually, one of the volumes will be converted to free space and the other will be expand to fill this free space. To determine the size of the two new volumes, the following command needs to be entered to get the sizes pertaining to the current volume.

   ```
   diskutil info disk0s2 | grep Size
   ```

   Below is my output from entering the above command.

   ```
   -bash-3.2# diskutil info disk0s2 | grep Size
      Disk Size:                267.6 GB (267575697408 Bytes) (exactly 522608784 512-Byte-Units)
      Device Block Size:        512 Bytes
      Allocation Block Size:    4096 Bytes
   ```

   The equation below can be used to compute the size of the new partitions in sectors.

   ```
   Partition Size in Sectors = Disk Size in 512-Byte-Units/16*(4096/Device Block Size)
   ```

   This equation can be evaluated by entering the command given below. You will need to replace the values of `522608784` and `512` with your values for `Disk Size in 512-Byte-Units` and `Device Block Size`, respectively.

   ```
   echo "Partition Size in Sectors = $((522608784/16*(4096/512)))"
   ```

   Below is my output from entering the above command.

   ```
   -bash-3.2# echo "Partition Size in Sectors = $((522608784/16*(4096/512)))"
   Partition Size in Sectors = 261304392
   ```

   These next commands will prevent the partition (`disk0s2`) containing the existing volume from mounting. Also, the new partitions created later will not be able to mount until after being formatted. You will need to replace the values of `261304392` and `512` with your values for `Partition Size in Sectors` and `Device Block Size`, respectively.

   ```
   diskutil unmount disk0s2
   dd if=/dev/zero count=100 bs=512 of=/dev/disk0s2
   dd if=/dev/zero count=100 bs=512 seek=261304392 of=/dev/disk0s2
   ```

   Below is my output from entering the above commands.

   ```
   -bash-3.2# diskutil unmount disk0s2
   Volume Macintosh HD on disk0s2 unmounted
   -bash-3.2# dd if=/dev/zero count=100 bs=512 of=/dev/disk0s2
   100+0 records in
   100+0 records out
   51200 bytes transferred in 0.024378 secs (2100249 bytes/sec)
   -bash-3.2# dd if=/dev/zero count=100 bs=512 seek=261304392 of=/dev/disk0s2
   100+0 records in
   100+0 records out
   51200 bytes transferred in 0.050295 secs (1017996 bytes/sec)
   ```

   Use the `gdisk` command to divide partition where OS X used to reside into two partitions of equal size. Here, I assume your EFI partition (/dev/disk0s1) is still mounted on `/Volumes/EFI`. If not, enter the command below.

   ```
   diskutil mount disk0s1
   ```

   The command below can be used to execute `gdisk`.

   ```
   /Volumes/EFI/gdisk /dev/disk0
   ```

   The above command is interactive. The table below lists the required entries. The commands and data need to be entered in the order given in the table.

   > Note: Read each comment and any applicable footnote carefully before making an entry.

   | Entries for 512 Byte Device Block Size | Entries for 4096 Byte Device Block Size | Comments |
   | --- | --- | --- |
   | `x` | `x` | Enter the experts' menu |
   | `l` | `l` | Change the sector alignment value |
   | `8` | `1` | New sector alignment value |
   | `m` | `m` | Return to main menu |
   | `p` | `p` | Display basic partition summary |
   | `d` | `d` | Delete a partition |
   | `2` | `2` | Partiton to delete |
   | `n` | `n` | Create a new partition |
   | `2` | `2` | Partition to create† |
   | `409640` | `76806` | Starting sector† |
   | `+261304392` | `+32663049` | Size in sectors* |
   | `AF00` | `AF00` | Hex code for HFS+ partition† |
   | `n` | `n` | Create a new partition |
   | `4` | `4` | Partition to create† |
   | `261714032` | `32739855` | Starting sector‡ |
   | `+261304392` | `+32663049` | Size in sectors* |
   | `AF00` | `AF00` | Hex code for HFS+ partition† |
   | `s` | `s` | Sort partition entries |
   | `p` | `p` | Display basic partition summary |
   | `w` | `w` | Write GPT to disk and exit |
   | `y` | `y` | Yes proceed to write and exit |

   > *You should enter the *Partition Size in Sectors* that you calculated earilier instead of the value shown. Note, the `+` character is significant and should not be omitted.
   >
   > †This should be the default value.
   >
   > ‡This should be the default value. However, the value you see will not be the same as shown in the table. The value you see will be the new second partition's starting sector plus size in sectors.

   Below is my output from using the `gdisk` command. The default values were used when appropriate.

   ```
   -bash-3.2# gdisk /dev/disk0
   GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 1.0.8

   Warning: Devices opened with shared lock will not have their
   partition table automatically reloaded!
   Partition table scan:
     MBR: protective
     BSD: not present
     APM: not present
     GPT: present

   Found valid GPT with protective MBR; using GPT.

   Command (? for help): x

   Expert command (? for help): l
   Enter the sector alignment value (1-65536, default = 2048): 8

   Expert command (? for help): m

   Command (? for help): p
   Disk /dev/disk0: 524288000 sectors, 250.0 GiB
   Sector size (logical): 512 bytes
   Disk identifier (GUID): D32269E7-0718-4BCC-A2BD-24ACA171AE82
   Partition table holds up to 128 entries
   Main partition table begins at sector 2 and ends at sector 33
   First usable sector is 34, last usable sector is 524287966
   Partitions will be aligned on 8-sector boundaries
   Total free space is 13 sectors (6.5 KiB)

   Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
      1              40          409639   200.0 MiB   EF00  EFI System Partition
      2          409640       523018423   249.2 GiB   AF00  Apple HFS/HFS+
      3       523018424       524287959   619.9 MiB   AB00  Recovery HD

   Command (? for help): d
   Partition number (1-3): 2

   Command (? for help): n
   Partition number (2-128, default 2): 
   First sector (34-524287966, default = 409640) or {+-}size{KMGTP}: 
   Last sector (409640-523018423, default = 523018423) or {+-}size{KMGTP}: +261304392
   Current type is AF00 (Apple HFS/HFS+)
   Hex code or GUID (L to show codes, Enter = AF00): 
   Changed type of partition to 'Apple HFS/HFS+'

   Command (? for help): n
   Partition number (4-128, default 4): 
   First sector (34-524287966, default = 261714032) or {+-}size{KMGTP}: 
   Last sector (261714032-523018423, default = 523018423) or {+-}size{KMGTP}: +261304392
   Current type is AF00 (Apple HFS/HFS+)
   Hex code or GUID (L to show codes, Enter = AF00): 
   Changed type of partition to 'Apple HFS/HFS+'

   Command (? for help): s
   You may need to edit /etc/fstab and/or your boot loader configuration!

   Command (? for help): p
   Disk /dev/disk0: 524288000 sectors, 250.0 GiB
   Sector size (logical): 512 bytes
   Disk identifier (GUID): D32269E7-0718-4BCC-A2BD-24ACA171AE82
   Partition table holds up to 128 entries
   Main partition table begins at sector 2 and ends at sector 33
   First usable sector is 34, last usable sector is 524287966
   Partitions will be aligned on 8-sector boundaries
   Total free space is 13 sectors (6.5 KiB)

   Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
      1              40          409639   200.0 MiB   EF00  EFI System Partition
      2          409640       261714031   124.6 GiB   AF00  Apple HFS/HFS+
      3       261714032       523018423   124.6 GiB   AF00  Apple HFS/HFS+
      4       523018424       524287959   619.9 MiB   AB00  Recovery HD

   Command (? for help): w

   Final checks complete. About to write GPT data. THIS WILL OVERWRITE EXISTING
   PARTITIONS!!

   Do you want to proceed? (Y/N): y
   OK; writing new GUID partition table (GPT) to /dev/disk0.
   Warning: Devices opened with shared lock will not have their
   partition table automatically reloaded!
   Warning: The kernel may continue to use old or deleted partitions.
   You should reboot or remove the drive.
   The operation has completed successfully.
   ```

   Enter the following command to get the identifiers for the two new `Apple_HFS` type partitions.

   ```
   diskutil list disk0
   ```

   Below is my output from entering the above command.

   > Note: The output is still showing the `Macintosh HD` as the name of `disk0s2`. This name will be updated later, when the `diskutil` is used to mount `disk0s2`.

   ```
   -bash-3.2# diskutil list disk0
   /dev/disk0
      #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
      0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        +268.4 GB   disk0
      1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
      2:                  Apple_HFS Macintosh HD            133.8 GB   disk0s2
      3:                  Apple_HFS                         133.8 GB   disk0s5
      4:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s3
   ```

   Enter the following command to format, mount and list the two new partitions. If your two new partitions have identifiers which differ from `disk0s2` or `disk0s5`, then make the appropriate substitutions.

   ```
   newfs_hfs -J -v Upper /dev/disk0s2
   newfs_hfs -J -v Lower /dev/disk0s5
   diskutil mount disk0s2
   diskutil mount disk0s5
   diskutil list disk0
   ```

   Below is my output from entering the above commands.

   ```
   -bash-3.2# newfs_hfs -J -v Upper /dev/disk0s2
   Initialized /dev/rdisk0s2 as a 125 GB case-insensitive HFS Plus volume with a 16384k journal
   -bash-3.2# newfs_hfs -J -v Lower /dev/disk0s5
   Initialized /dev/rdisk0s5 as a 125 GB case-insensitive HFS Plus volume with a 16384k journal
   -bash-3.2# diskutil mount disk0s2
   Volume Upper on disk0s2 mounted
   -bash-3.2# diskutil mount disk0s5
   Volume Lower on disk0s5 mounted
   -bash-3.2# diskutil list disk0
   /dev/disk0
      #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
      0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        +268.4 GB   disk0
      1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
      2:                  Apple_HFS Upper                   133.8 GB   disk0s2
      3:                  Apple_HFS Lower                   133.8 GB   disk0s5
      4:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s3
   ```

   Quit the Terminal application.
3. Open Safari by selecting "Get Help Online". Under Safari Preferences, set "File download location:" to the `Lower` device, as shown below.

   [image: Safari preferences]

   At this point, I offer two options. The first option would be to use website http://maclinks.publicvm.com (or https://maclinks.publicvm.com) to get the URL or link necessary to download the `InstallMacOSX.dmg` file for Mountain Lion from Apple. If you use the first option, then you can skip the rest of this step. The second option would be to proceed with the rest of this step.

   Next, goto https://support.apple.com/kb/DL2076. If you are using a newer version of Safari, then a `Download` button will appear, as shown below. If the button appears then select the button, download the `InstallMacOSX.dmg` file to `/Volumes/Lower` and proceed to the next step. Otherwise, complete the rest of this step.

   [image: with button]

   Most likely, the `Download` button will not appear, as shown below.

   [image: without button]

   From menu bar, select `File`→`Save As…`, then set the format to `Page Source`, as shown below. When finished, select the `Save` button, the quit Safari.

   [image: save page source]

   From the menu bar, select `Utilities`→`Terminal` to open a Terminal window and enter the command below. This will output text containing the URL assigned to the missing `Download` button.

   ```
   grep updates /Volumes/Lower/Mac\ OS X\ Mountain\ Lion\ Installer.html
   ```

   When I run the above command, the following was output.

   ```
   "metaUrl": "https://updates.cdn-apple.com/2021/macos/031-0627-20210614-90D11F33-1A65-42DD-BBEA-E1D9F43A6B3F/InstallMacOSX.dmg",
   ```

   From which, the following URL can be extracted.

   ```
   https://updates.cdn-apple.com/2021/macos/031-0627-20210614-90D11F33-1A65-42DD-BBEA-E1D9F43A6B3F/InstallMacOSX.dmg
   ```

   From your output, copy the Url, quit Terminal, open Safari and paste the URL as the location to open. This should download the `InstallMacOSX.dmg` file to `/Volumes/Lower`.
4. Quit Safari and open Terminal. Enter the following commands to replace the `Upper` volume with with a bootable Mountain Lion installer.

   ```
   cd /Volumes/Lower
   hdiutil attach InstallMacOSX.dmg
   pkgutil --expand-full /Volumes/Install\ Mac\ OS\ X/InstallMacOSX.pkg full
   diskutil eject /Volumes/Install\ Mac\ OS\ X
   asr --source full/InstallMacOSX.pkg/InstallESD.dmg --target /Volumes/Upper --erase
   ```
5. From menu bar, select ``→`Starup Disk…`, then select OS X, 10.8.5 on the disk “Mac OS X Install ESD”, as shown below. Next, select the `Restart…` button, then confirm the restart.

   [image: startup disk for ML]

   Let the Mac boot to the Mountain Lion Installer.
6. Prepare a volume for the installation of Mountain Lion.

   > A some point, the original Yosemite recovery partition will be removed. Making a backup of this partition is optional. If all goes well, you will not need to use the backup. You can choose one of the two options below. Do not choose both.

   - Option that removes the original Yosemite recovery partition.

     Use the Disk Utility to erase the `Lower` volume. Select the `Mac OS Extended (Journaled)` format and enter `Macintosh HD` name. When finished, quit the Disk Utility.
   - Option that backups the original Yosemite recovery partition.

     Open a Terminal window and enter the commands given below.

     ```
     diskutil unmount disk0s3
     newfs_hfs -J -v "Mountain Lion" /dev/disk0s3
     diskutil mount disk0s3
     dd if=/dev/disk0s4 of=/Volumes/Mountain\ Lion/YosemiteRecovery.bin bs=1m
     ```

     When finished, quit the Terminal application.
7. Select `Reinstall OS X` and install OS X Mountain Lion on the `Mountain Lion` volume. Proceed and install Mountain Lion. When asked to enter an Apple ID, I chose to skip. Also, when asked to register this device, I chose to skip.
8. Open Safari and goto "How to get old versions of macOS" (https://support.apple.com/HT211683). Under the section "Use Safari to download macOS on your Mac", select the [OS X Yosemite 10.10](http://updates-http.cdn-apple.com/2019/cert/061-41343-20191023-02465f92-3ab5-4c92-bfe2-b725447a070d/InstallMacOSX.dmg) link to download  `InstallMacOSX.dmg` to your `Downloads` folder. When finished, quit Safari.
9. Use the `InstallMacOSX.dmg` file in your `Downloads` folder to install the "Install OS X Yosemite" application to the `/Applications` folder. When finished, use the Finder to eject the `Install OS X` volume.
10. Prepare a volume for the installation of Yosemite. Use the Disk Utility to erase the `Mac OS X Install ESD` volume. Select the `Mac OS Extended (Journaled)` format and enter `Macintosh HD` name. When finished, quit the Disk Utility.

    > A some point, the `Mountain Lion` volume will be removed. If you previously made a backup `YosemiteRecovery.bin` file on this volume, then use the Finder to copy the `YosemiteRecovery.bin` file from `Mountain Lion` volume to the `Macintosh HD` volume. Making this copy is optional. If all goes well, you will not need to use this copy.
11. Use the "Install OS X Yosemite" application to install Yosemite to  the `Macintosh HD` volume.
12. Remove Mountain Lion and reclaim the space back to the `Macintosh HD` volume by choosing one of the two options below. Do not choose both.

    - From Yosemite, use the Disk Utility to remove the Mountain Lion partition. Next, quit the Disk Utility and then open the Disk Utility. Finally, use the Disk Utility to resize the the "Macintosh HD" partition to maximum size. When finished, quit the Disk Utility.
    - Open the Terminal and enter the following commands to remove the `Mountain Lion` volume and add the free space to the `Macintosh HD` volume.

      ```
      diskutil erasevolume free none "Mountain Lion"
      diskutil resizevolume "Macintosh HD" R
      ```

      When finished, quit the Terminal application.

### Other References

[Create a Bootable DVD Copy of OS X Lion Installer](https://www.lifewire.com/create-bootable-dvd-copy-os-x-lion-installer-2260330)

Comment: This is such an amazing answer - my hat is off to you, again, for such precise and comprehensive solutions to keep old hardware running.

Comment: I couldn't agree more. Only last week one of my neighbours popped around with an old MacBook Pro needing me to sort out a problem. The point being that people still have and use old devices, so preserving these types of answers can be a godsend for people. :)