# Mac OS X Lion (10.7) install error

Tags: macos, internet-recovery

I had an old MacBookAir5,2 (mid 2012). It had Windows 10 running on it *(on its own without Boot Camp)* & I wanted to use it in macOS. So, I surfed the web and did as below.

Step 1: Cloned my entire drive (which had Windows) on an external hard drive.

Step 2: Used Internet Recovery to format the drive **Mac OS Extended (Journaled)**, and then the problem started.

Step 3: I shut down the system as instructed and once again launched Internet Recovery in order to install the macOS.

After all the standard procedure, this popped up and I don't know what to do from here. Where can I find those "additional components" and how to install them?

[image]

Comment: Where can i find those "additional components" & how to install those :(

Comment: Have you tried Option-Command-R during startup? This is suppose to offer the latest macOS that is compatible with your Mac. See this Apple [website](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204904). Success will depend on which versions of OS X and/or macOS you previous had installed on your Mac.

Comment: -David Anderson >.                                  I tried it but it just booted into (Mac OS X Utilities) and the same happened here also

Comment: Do you have another Mac or can you boot this Mac from Windows on the external drive?

Comment: I don't have any other Mac nor my friends have any & I don't think I can boot from that external drive since I just copied all the necessary files. :(

Comment: You can download the installation files directly from Apple and use the files to install Lion or Mountain Lion. However, the procedure is fairly long and tedious. Sort of a last resort type of thing. See this [answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/431445/trying-to-reinstall-macos-after-wiping-hd-but-cant-get-past-apple-id-and-safa/431897#431897) for an example. Do you thing you are up to trying something that complex?

Answer (score 1):

The latest version of Mac OS X Lion (10.7.5) was released in October 2012, so it's possible that as of April 2023 Apple has removed the relevant files from the server that Internet Recovery is referencing for installer data.

Apple has the full installer for Mac OS X 10.7.5 available for free, via the link below:

https://support.apple.com/kb/DL2077

Apple also sells the full Lion installer on a bootable USB drive:

https://www.apple.com/shop/product/D6106Z/A

Comment: What make you think Apple sells a full Lion install on a bootable USB drive?

Comment: They really should have removed that shop page by now; they made Lion free 2 or 3 years ago. The shop page just buys you a code allowing you to download it from behind a now out of date paywall. It's not a shipped product.

Comment: Meh… the other link is also an old one - current download is at https://support.apple.com/HT211683

Comment: A small Update here, it turns out that this is happened due to some certification related things. And a way out for this was to change the date to sometime  after the os was launched newly. I had to change the date using terminal in the recovery mide with some "sudo" Command. And that also failed, still the same result as before :(